# ASIHTTPRequest Asynchronous Crash When Changing Views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I'm using ASIHttpRequest to recieve data from an xml file. However during an asynchronous request as soon as i change the view (back to the previous view using the navigation controller) the application crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the main.m

This only happens while the request is being made.

Below is my code:

```
-(void)ProcessXML{

    //Set url from string to url
    NSURL *theurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/2smssupport.xml"];

    asirequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:theurl];
    [asirequest setDelegate:self];
    [asirequest startAsynchronous];

}


- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{


    NSLog(@"Saving to Defaults");
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
    xmlSaved = responseData;

    prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setObject:responseData forKey:@"xmlDownload"];
    rssParser = [[RssParser alloc] loadXMLbyURL:xmlSaved];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"%@",[prefs dataForKey:@"xmlDownload"]);

}
```

The Process XML method triggers the request and the then received data is processed in the RequestFinished.

There must be something i'm missing with the ASIHTTPRequest but i don't know what it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This block of code should fix it:

```
    -(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
        [request clearDelegatesAndCancel]
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the view is being release then the delegate you set on the request is now invalid. Make sure you set the delegate to nil on the view dealloc and also stop the request.

Comment: how would i do this?  I have set the asirequest to nil in the dealloc and it still crashes

Comment: [asirequest setDelegate:nil];

Comment: I take that back, it did work... but now it hits me with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error somewhere in the asihttprequest class

Comment: Turn on Zombies - add NSZombieEnabled to YES in the executable arguments and see the line it breaks on, it will show the object which is being over-released...

Answer (score 0):

Are you deallocating the `ASIHTTPRequest` object when you leave the current view? My guess is that the delegate methods are being called after your view controller has been released.

--

@Simon is right that you do need to set the delegate to nil. What I would do is:

1. Create an `ASIHTTPRequest` property in your class and set that property in your `ProcessXML` method. This simplifies memory management and ensures that the request object will stick around while you need it.
2. In both your `dealloc` method and your `requestFinished` methods, set the request delegate to nil and set `self.request = nil;`

At the very least, you should set the delegate to nil in your `requestFinished` method, but you need to remember to stop your request from running if you navigate away from this view controller before it returns, hence setting it to nil in the `dealloc` method as well.

Comment: This is probably correct, how will i go about resolving the problem then? memory allocation on the iphone confuses me somewhat

Comment: It is self-retaining, you don't need to retain OR release it. But as per my answer, you need to set the delegate to nil.

Comment: where do i need to set the delegate to nil then? in the dealloc?

Comment: @Simon - The more common term it is "autoreleased". It's marked for release when the autorelease pool drains at the end of the current run loop. "Self-retaining" implies that it can keep itself in existence for arbitrary time, which it can't.

Comment: I can call [self retain] then [self release] whenever I like. I am QUITE aware of autorelease... check my bio ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `asirequest` object isn't being retained anywhere, so it's being deallocated after `ProcessXML` returns.

Comment: even if the view is changed? the request happens on what looks a background thread.

Comment: It is self-retaining, you don't need to retain OR release it.

Comment: @Simon Lee, what makes you say that?  I've just checked the documentation and the source, and it doesn't look like it to me.

Comment: I mean the request is made on the main thread, but everythings working in the background. This has always stumped me so i just usually use the syncroneous request.

i get the following error now: Attempting to create USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME variable with block that isn't in the frame. || assigned the [asirequest setDelegate:nil] in the dealloc causes the app to crash instantly

Comment: - (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request startAsynchronous];
}

Comment: Ah, just checked the source a bit further.  When you start an asynchronous request, it adds itself to an internal `NSOperationQueue` which is retained and, in turn, retains the request.  Can't say I like that approach, but it has the effect you describe.

Comment: You should note though, that it's not "self-retaining" - for example, if you create a request with a convenience method and expect it to just stick around, that isn't the case unless there's an active queue.

Comment: No, but once you start an async call you don't need to worry about it, this is what I was getting at. It will stay in existence as long as it needs to to complete the request.

Answer (score 0):

NSZombieEnabled helps you a lot. You can tell which object is causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS.